# Casting an int to a string in Python

Tags: python, string, integer, concatenation

I want to be able to generate a number of text files with the names fileX.txt where X is some integer:

```
for i in range(key):
    filename = "ME" + i + ".txt" //Error here! Can't concat a string and int
    filenum = filename
    filenum = open(filename , 'w')
```

Does anyone else know how to do the filename = "ME" + i  part so I get a list of files with the names: "ME0.txt" , "ME1.txt" , "ME2.txt" , and etc

Comment: Python is (more) strongly typed than languages like Perl and Rexx, and won't do implicit type conversions.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
x = 1
y = "foo" + str(x)
```

Please see the Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#str

Answer (score 19):

For Python versions prior to 2.6, use the [string formatting operator `%`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
filename = "ME%d.txt" % i
```

For 2.6 and later, use the [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) method:

```
filename = "ME{0}.txt".format(i)
```

Though the first example still works in 2.6, the second one is preferred.

If you have more than 10 files to name this way, you might want to add leading zeros so that the files are ordered correctly in directory listings:

```
filename = "ME%02d.txt" % i
filename = "ME{0:02d}.txt".format(i)
```

This will produce file names like `ME00.txt` to `ME99.txt`. For more digits, replace the `2` in the examples with a higher number (eg, `ME{0:03d}.txt`).

Comment: I would not use this in any case without a static filename. If it comes from user input, a lot of odd stuff could happen.

Comment: @Bachsau -- Sorry, I fail to see what user input has anything to do with that. Validating user input is a completely separate concern.

Comment: `str.format()` strings have a lot of special characters. You would need to escape them all, or it will break when a user defined string cotains any of them. So when you're working with user input and the string isn't overly complex, like just putting a number between filename and extension, it is probably best to just use string concatenation: `"name" + int(num) + "ext"`. User input is everything not defined in your own code, including names you got from a file, directory or the network.

Comment: Sure, but again: Validating user input is a separate concern. Of course you should not directly feed user input into `str.format()`, but then again: You should not use user input without checks for file names in any case. But what does this have to do with this question?

Answer (score 4):

Either:

```
"ME" + str(i)
```

Or:

```
"ME%d" % i
```

The second one is usually preferred, especially if you want to build a string from several tokens.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str()` to cast it, or formatters:

```
"ME%d.txt" % (num,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here answer for your code as whole:

```
key =10

files = ("ME%i.txt" % i for i in range(key))

#opening
files = [ open(filename, 'w') for filename in files]

# processing
for i, file in zip(range(key),files):
    file.write(str(i))
# closing
for openfile in files:
    openfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Works on Python 3 and Python 2.7

```
for i in range(50):
    filename = "example{:03d}.txt".format(i)
    print(filename)
```

Use format `{:03d}` to have 3 digits with leading 0, it's a great trick to have the files appear in the right order when looking at them in the explorer. Leave brackets empty `{}` for default formatting.

```
# output
example000.txt
example001.txt
example002.txt
example003.txt
```