# python error; unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I am new to python and while I am working on this code I keep getting an error for line 8 saying "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'", but i have no idea how to fix it/ what is wrong with it.

```
minTot = 0
stepTot = 0
min = int(raw_input("Input the number of minutes (0 to exit): "))
if min == 0:
    print "No minutes input."
else:
    while min != 0:
        minTot = minTot + min
        stepRate = int(raw_input("Input the step rate: "))
        stepTot = stepTot + stepRate * min
        min = raw_input("Input the next number of minutes (0 to exit): ")
    print "\nTotal number of minutes:", min
    print "Total number of steps:", stepTot
    # Average is rounded down.
print " Average step rate per minute : ", minTot / stepTot
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using Python 3.x? Because it doesn't have `raw_input` function.

Comment: Line 11 is missing an `int()` call and this is python 2

Comment: `min` is a [Python builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min), so you should probably pick another name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Python 2.7 I believe. (You can confirm that with `python --version`) And the problem is in this line

```
min = raw_input("Input the next number of minutes (0 to exit): ")
```

`raw_input` returns a string and you need to explicitly convert that to a number with `int`, like this

```
min = int(raw_input("Input the next number of minutes (0 to exit): "))
```

If you don't do that, `min` will be a string and on the next iteration, when it reaches

```
minTot = minTot + min
```

`minTot` will be a number and you are trying to add a string with a number. That is not possible. That is why Python throws that error.

Apart from that, [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) is a builtin function's name. You might not want to shadow that function. So, use someother variable name.

Comment: I would highly suggest looking into casting, the basic idea is str(yourVariable). This will cast yourVariable as a string. You can read more at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944876/casting-an-int-to-a-string-in-python Note you can also cast strings to ints, ints to strings, objects, and on, and on.